# TypeError: worker.load is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, tesseract.js

I use vue.js and nuxt.js when i want to extract text from pdf or image file. it doesn't seem work. I don't know why.
this is my first time to ask question if you want more some information. please feel free to ask me. I'm stuck with this error for 4 days T^T. I really need help.

i try to fix about this error. All of I want it's just fix error.

```js
async parseFile() {
      if (this.uploadedFile) {
        const fileType = this.getFileType(this.uploadedFile.name);
        if (fileType === "image") {
          const worker = createWorker();
          await worker.load();
          await worker.loadLanguage("eng");
          await worker.initialize("eng");
          const {
            data: { text },
          } = await worker.recognize(this.uploadedFile);
          console.log(text);
          await worker.terminate();
        } else if (fileType === "pdf") {
          const fileReader = new FileReader();
          fileReader.onload = async () => {
            const typedArray = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result);
            const pdf = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(typedArray).promise;
            const numPages = pdf.numPages;
            let pdfText = "";
            for (let i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
              const page = await pdf.getPage(i);
              const content = await page.getTextContent();
              const pageText = content.items.map((item) => item.str).join(" ");
              pdfText += pageText + "\n";
            }
            console.log(pdfText);
          };
          fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.uploadedFile);
        }
```

Comment: From what [I see](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/blob/master/docs/examples.md) it's asynchronous and should be `const worker = await createWorker();`. So `worker` is a `Promise` now, and that's why it doesn't have `load()` and the others.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion,
Check if the function createWorker() is not properly imported or if there is an issue with the library you are using and
also check that you have installed the necessary dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Use this version = "tesseract.js": "^2.1.5"
it will run.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Update the syntax to the version of Tesseract you are using. Try replacing

```
const worker = createWorker();
await worker.load();
await worker.loadLanguage("eng");
wait worker.initialize("eng");
```

with

```
const worker = await createWorker("eng")
```